Hyperlink with formula field to redirect to custom app page along with recordId in url?
HYPERLINK('/lightning/n/Rejected_OIDs?recordId='+Id, Conflict_Lead__c )
I am using above formula field to navigate to lightning page when user click on this formula field.
once I click on the field it navigating to app page  while loading it is fetching recordId. After loading in the url it appearing until /n/Rejected__OIDs.
But I want to capture recordId from url and Need to use in app page ?
How should I get url along with recordId?
